# Override plugin styles via my custom theme

Tags: plugins, css

So as not to rewrite the plugin interface styles or modify the current ones, I want to add new styles for this plugin through my theme, for this I need to disable them, I do this through: `remove_filters_with_method_name`

```
remove_filters_with_method_name( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_plugin_assets', 10 );
```

now how can I use my custom css in such a way that the plugin can get them?

Comment: `remove_filters_with_method_name()` is not a WordPress function, and if you don't want to remove the plugin styles, why are you using it?

Comment: because I need to disable the plugin styles, and then use my styles to customize the front that the plugin draws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugins don't need to "get" styles. You just need to enqueue your own stylesheet with styles for the markup used by that plugin. If the plugin is on the front-end, your styles could even just be added to your child theme, or *Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS*. If the plugin elements you want to style are in the admin, just enqueue your stylesheet with [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/).